# Use gulp or grunt in non Asp.Net 5 project

Tags: c#, gruntjs, gulp

Is there a way to use gulp build tasks in a C# class library or portable library in Visual Studio 2015? Currently I feel like this is only possible in a Asp.Net 5 project.

Why I want to do so? Because I am going to use [CefGlue](https://bitbucket.org/xilium/xilium.cefglue/wiki/Home) and don't need a web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is super easy. Just add a package.json and gulpfile.js file to your project root. You can now run the gulp task from the Task Runner Explorer (available on right-click).

Comment: Also don't forget to reopen Visual Studio. In my case only after that Gulp started working.